# How to Compare two String for a particular value in Java

Tags: java, string

I have two strings generated from two different XML. Like this

```
s1= <xml><timestamp>10.22</timestamp></xml>
s2 = <xml><timestamp>10.24</timestamp></xml>
```

I need to compare these two strings and remove a particular tags from these Strings and compare the rest of the string if they are equal or not.

Example: I want to remove the timestamp tag: then s1 and s2 will look like this:

```
s1= <xml></xml>
s2 = <xml></xml>
```

I am not allowed to use marshalling and unmarshalling api in this. I have also written a code on this but it does not handle nested tags.

```
public boolean compareString(final String s1, final String s2, String stringToBeRemoved) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(s1);
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(s2);
        int intialstartIndex;

        //first String evaluation starts here
        int startIndex1 = sb1.indexOf(stringToBeRemoved);
        intialstartIndex = startIndex1;

        //handling for short expression to reach to the top of the starttag
        do {
            startIndex1--;
        } while(sb1.charAt(startIndex1) != '<');


        int endIndex1 = sb1.indexOf(stringToBeRemoved,intialstartIndex+stringToBeRemoved.length());
        endIndex1 = endIndex1 + stringToBeRemoved.length()+1;

        //handling for short expression to reach to end of close tag
        do {
            endIndex1++;
        } while(sb1.charAt(endIndex1) != '>');

        //second string evaluation starts here

        int startIndex2 = sb2.indexOf(stringToBeRemoved);
        intialstartIndex = startIndex2;
        do {
            startIndex2--;
        } while(sb2.charAt(startIndex1) != '<');


        int endIndex2 = sb2.indexOf(stringToBeRemoved,intialstartIndex+stringToBeRemoved.length());
        endIndex2 = endIndex2 + stringToBeRemoved.length()+1;

        do {
            endIndex2++;
        } while(sb2.charAt(endIndex2) != '>');

        if(startIndex1 == -1 || startIndex2 == -1){
    throw new Exception();
        }
        else {
            sb1 = sb1.delete(startIndex1,endIndex1);
            sb2 = sb2.delete(startIndex2,endIndex2);
        }
        return sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString());

    }
```

Any help suggestion/any utils is highly appreciated on this. I am open for regex pattern as well.thanks

Comment: You know your tag, so you have <tag> and </tag> and can find their positions. Then you can check if in the string between your tags are other <> so you can delete the content of your tag as you need it.

Comment: You can use XML parser to parse your strings and extract values you need. Look at DOM or SAX XML parsers in Java.

Comment: @JakubH As mentioned in his question: "I am not allowed to use marshalling and unmarshalling api in this."

Comment: NB: there might be some better duplicate, feel free do use [the site search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+tag+%5Bjava%5D)